# How do I grant other users permission to write to SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite

I faced a strange error related to permissions for a SQLite database.

I type in bash

```
rm -f test.db
sqlite3 test.db 'CREATE TABLE t (qwe, qqq)'
chmod 666 test.db
sudo -u another-user sqlite3 test.db 'INSERT INTO t VALUES (4, 2)'
```

It prints

> Error: unable to open database file

It prints the same if I change an owner of `test.db` file to `another-user`.
But if I try to insert the record on behalf of root or me, there is no any
error, and it's inserted successfully.

What's the troubles?

An output of `getfacl test.db` is the following

> ```
> # file: test.db
> # owner: mymedia
> # group: mymedia
> user::rw-
> group::rw-
> other::rw-
> ```

AppArmor has no profiles related to SQLite, SeLinux is disabled. I was
experimenting on Ubuntu 16.04. The version of SQLite is 3.11.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem seems to be not with file permissions, but with directory. Check if a directory where your database file is placed has proper permissions for `another-user`.

Comment: Oh, thank you! When I gave write access `another-user` to the folder, it solved the problem. It seems SQLite creates temporary files near the database file